# mvc index with many to many firstordefault

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I got stuck with a problem, where I feel like I am overlooking something.

I am trying to get an one to one like result from a one to many relation for an asp.net mvc index view.

I have got three classes

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public int RelationID { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int? ContactID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
}
```

The result should include the following

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried LINQ and Lambda expressions to get the data into the viewmodel e.g.

```
        var contacts = from contact in db.Contacts
                   .Include(relation => relation.Relation
                        .Where(s => s.ContactID == contact.ContactID)
                        .OrderByDescending(d => d.StartDate)
                        .FirstOrDefault())
                   select new ContactViewModel
                    {
                        ContactID = contact.ContactID,
                        Name = contact.Name,
                        Position = relation.Position,
                        Company = relation.Company.CompanyName
                    };
```

But I do not get it to work...

The view should display a asp.net mvc Index view with

```
Name  Position   Company
Hans  Boss       Sausage House
Tom   Manager    Burger Building
```

Query the relation is no Problem and get the related Contacts and Companies, but not every Contact has a position and some have more than one. So I would like to include all Contacts and all current relations.

I know that it would be easier to either change the relation or my idea how the view should look like.

But maybe someone can help anyway.

Thank you!

UPDATE

Thank you for the quick response and you are absolutly right with your comments. But my problem was not the compilation of the query. This query won't work anyway. I am stuck how to get a model filled with the desired result and if this is possible to do. I will probably have to take a different approach and I tried already a few. Maybe somebody can help with a query that has the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Include` if the end result is a projection, and you can't filter `Include`d expressions.

But this is easy if you use the `let` keyword:

```
var contacts = from contact in db.Contacts
               let relation = contact.Relation
                              .OrderByDescending(d => d.StartDate)
                              .FirstOrDefault()
               select new ContactViewModel
               {
                   ContactID = contact.ContactID,
                   Name = contact.Name,
                   Position = relation.Position,
                   Company = relation.Company.CompanyName
               };
```

BTW, do yourself a favor and use plural nouns for collection property names.

Comment: Thank you! I added the two missing "s". I was only a mistake in the post since I did not copy the code from the project. I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

Edited my previous code for a new approach:

```
var contacts = from relation in db.Relations
    join contact in db.Contacts on relation.ContactID equals contact.ContactID
    join company in db.Companies on relation.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
    orderby relation.StartDate descending
    select new ContactViewModel
    {
        ContactID = contact.ContactID,
        Name = contact.Name,
        Position = relation.Position,
        Company = company.CompanyName
    };
```

Though I'm not sure if I understood the definition `public virtual ICollection<Relation> Relation { get; set; }` correctly.

For further explanation see MSDN documentation:

- `join` clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx
- `orderby` clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx

Made a little diagram, I think I'm just gonna leave it here as well for clarification:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: Thank you! You understood the model correct even though I forgot a "s" behind the second "Relation". My problem is a little different. Not Evers contact has a relation. But I need all contacts and the most recent relation or none.